# How to add a captcha field to typo3 form

Tags: typo3

in Extension Manager I uploaded sr_freecap_2.2.0.t3x ... but I have no idea how to use it or how can I add a captcha field into my form. What should I do? Thank you for answers, indeed.

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

The extension is for programmed plugins, not for forms build using the included form plugin.
It comes with a manual that describes on how to do that. Check the `doc/manual.swx` inside the extension folder or view the lastest version on the official server:
http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/sr_freecap/